# Query executes as 1 equals 1 instead of null check

Tags: .net, nhibernate, linq-to-sql, linq-to-nhibernate

I am trying to select all the rows where the 'Value' column is null or whitespace. It is of type nvarchar and is allowed nulls.

When executed the following query does not produce the correct sql.

```
current.Where(
            a =>
            a.Data.All(ad => ad.AccountTag.Id != currentTag.Item1)
            || a.Data.Any(ad => ad.AccountTag.Id == currentTag.Item1 && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currentTag.Item2)))
```

The string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace function converts to `1 /* @p3 */ = 1`

I've tried using the above function and also using `currentTag.Item2 == null || currentTag.Item2.Equals(string.Empty)` both with the same results.

Full SQL below

```
select data2_.Id from   [isnapshot.Client].[dbo].AccountData data2_
    where  account0_.Id = data2_.ClientAccountId
    and data2_.AccountTagId = 1 /* @p2 */
    and 1 /* @p3 */ = 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is correct. `currentTag` is a local variable that has nothing to do with the query. Therefore the expression `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currentTag.Item2)` will be evaluated *before* it even is converted to SQL and the result is either `true` (1) or `false` (0), which will be the value of `p3`.

Comment: It's only when someone else looks at your code you realise what an idiot you are. `currentTag.Item2` should have been `ad.Value` Would never have noticed if you didn't point it out. Thank you

Comment: @JLevett: Sometimes you are just blind for the most obvious things. It happens to everyone once in a while :-)